# Why is the XmlDocument Validate event handler not getting hit?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, .net-2.0

I have this code:

```
  // Load the document
  XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

  // use the stream and have it close when it is finished
  using ( argInputStream )
  {
    xmlDocument.Load( argInputStream );
    xmlDocument.Schemas.Add( XmlSchema.Read( argSchemaStream, null ) );
    xmlDocument.Validate( ValidationEventHandler );
  }

// this is not getting hit
void ValidationEventHandler( object sender, ValidationEventArgs e )
{
  switch ( e.Severity )
  {
    case XmlSeverityType.Error:
      Console.WriteLine( "Error: {0}", e.Message );
      break;
    case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
      Console.WriteLine( "Warning {0}", e.Message );
      break;
  }
}
```

top line of my XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because your document is valid, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got some code validating xml using this construction.

```
var schemaReader = new XmlTextReader(argSchemaStream);
var schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
schema.Add(null, schemaReader);

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add(schema);
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(XmlReader.Create(argInputStream, settings));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the correct way of validating; try this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx). Basically, the schema seems to go with the XmlReaderSettings instead.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas.Add(...);
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(..., settings);
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(reader);

document.Validate(eventHandler);
```

Comment: -1 It is perfectly acceptable to load XML schemas into the `XmlDocument.Schemas` property as the question author is doing. Also, you said *the schema seems to go with the XmlReaderSettings instead*... but where do the `XmlReaderSettings` go? That's right... into the `XmlDocument` via the `XmlReader`... so it's actually quicker doing it the question author's way.

Comment: @Sheridan, the reason I said `I don't think it is the correct way of validating` was in the context in which the code was written... I was basically pointing out that `When an XmlDocument object is initialized with XML data from an XmlReader object, the XmlSchemaSet object is loaded from the Schemas property of the XmlReader object.` [XmlDocument.Schemas, remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.schemas.aspx)

Comment: I'm really not sure what you were trying to say in your response, but you've really just made *my* point for me with the link you provided to the `XmlDocument.Schemas` page on MSDN... it says *the XmlSchemaSet object is loaded from the Schemas property of the XmlReader object*... [and my point is]... it is loaded *into* the `XmlDocument.Schemas` property `XmlSchemaSet`... just where the question author put it in the first place.