# Updating XmlValidatingReader function to use XMLReader?

Tags: .net, xml, validation, xsd, xmlreader

I am trying to find an alternative to the following function, which is using the obsolete System.xml.XmlValidatingReader(). How can I adapt this code to work with XMLReader, which is what Visual Studio is suggesting as an alternative? Feel free to post a response in C# or VB.NET. The xmlString I am passing into the function is the raw xml which is referencing the XSD schema.

```
    'VALIDATE XML
    Public Shared Function validateXml(ByVal xmlString As String) As XmlDocument
        xmlErrorStr = ""
        Dim strReader As New StringReader(xmlString)
        Dim xmlr As New XmlTextReader(strReader)
        Dim xmlvread As New XmlValidatingReader(xmlr)

        ' Set the validation event handler
        AddHandler xmlvread.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf ValidationCallBack

        Try
            While (xmlvread.Read)
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            xmlErrorStr = "<Error>" & vbCrLf & "<Exception>The XML document is invalid or malformed</Exception>" & vbCrLf & "</Error>"
        End Try

        'Close the reader.
        xmlvread.Close()
        strReader.Close()

        Dim xmlDocument As New XmlDocument


        xmlDocument.LoadXml("<Errors>" & xmlErrorStr & "</Errors>")

        Return xmlDocument
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a validating reader by passing appropriately configured `XmlReaderSettings` to one of the `XmlReader.Create()` method overloads.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/9khb6435.aspx for an overview and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationtype.aspx for a more complete example.

Comment: Your references are correct and to the point; for all I know this may be the reason why some of your other answers were downvoted, or that this one isn't yet upvoted, but here on SO the expectation seems to be that more info should be provided with an answer - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806346/single-pass-read-and-validate-xml-vs-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp/9812386#9812386)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902908/why-is-the-xmldocument-validate-event-handler-not-getting-hit/10903288#10903288) are interesting to look at for similarity...