# Cannot debug into XmlDocument Validation Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, xmldocument, xml-validation

I am unable to debug into the XmlDocument Validate event handler. I am trying to debug through some code however I can never reach it.

Class A

```
XmlDoc.Validate(ValidationEventHandler);
public virtual void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e){
    //SomeCode
}
```

Class B: Class A

```
public override void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    //Some code
}
```

Breakpoints arent hitting in either one of the events handlers.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902908/why-is-the-xmldocument-validate-event-handler-not-getting-hit and others on SO. Please try searching for previous answers, or if the ones you find are not useful to you, please give an example that shows why.

Comment: @PhillipH This isnt a duplicate. The Event Handler is still being called I just cannot debug into it.

Comment: Are you saying that when you put a breakpoint on the code that you've commented out as "/// some code" that breakpoint is never hit ? If you put some System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() into the "///some code" section the Diagnostics are written ?